# C# Get Value for Custom Combobox on Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I needed a combobox on a datagridview which allows wildcard search. With the datagridviewcomboboxcolumn, it allows only startswith search. So, I leveraged the [EasyCompletionComboBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/755707/ComboBox-with-Suggestions-Based-on-Loose-Character) which performs wildcard as well as regex search. Since it had to be used in a datagridviewcolumn, I had to create a custom comboBox column.

I have been fairly successful in implementing it, but I'm not able to get the Selected value (value member) of the combobox. I'm getting the data member. Even though I'm populating the combobox datatable with the required values. Maybe something is wrong with the ECComboBoxEditingControl class.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
class ECComboBoxColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public ECComboBoxColumn() : base(new ECComboBoxCell())
    {
    }
    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ECComboBoxCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a ECComboBoxCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}

class ECComboBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public ECComboBoxCell()
    : base()
{
        // Use the short date format.
        //this.Style.Format = "d";
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
        initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
            dataGridViewCellStyle);
        ECComboBoxEditingControl ctl =
            DataGridView.EditingControl as ECComboBoxEditingControl;
        // Use the default row value when Value property is null.
        if (this.Value == null)
        {
            ctl.SelectedIndex = -1;//(String)this.DefaultNewRowValue;
        }
        else
        {
            ctl.SelectedItem = (String)this.Value;
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses.
            return typeof(ECComboBoxEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.

            return typeof(String);
        }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            // Use the current date and time as the default value.
            return "";
        }
    }
}

class ECComboBoxEditingControl : EasyCompletionComboBox, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    DataGridView dataGridView;
    private bool valueChanged = false;
    int rowIndex;

    public ECComboBoxEditingControl()
    {
        // this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        this.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue 
    // property.
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.SelectedValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is Decimal)
            {

                    this.SelectedItem = value;
            }
        }
    }

    // Implements the 
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method.
    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
        DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return this.GetItemText(this.SelectedItem);
    }

    // Implements the 
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method.
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
        DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        this.ForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
        this.BackColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex 
    // property.
    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return rowIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            rowIndex = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey 
    // method.
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
        Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit 
    // method.
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        // No preparation needs to be done.
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property.
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .EditingControlDataGridView property.
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView;
        }
        set
        {
            dataGridView = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .EditingControlValueChanged property.
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return valueChanged;
        }
        set
        {
            valueChanged = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .EditingPanelCursor property.
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Cursor;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell
        // have changed.
        valueChanged = true;
        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(eventargs);
    }   
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    EasyCompletionComboBox cmbProject;
    DataTable dtProjects;
    int projectComboBoxPopulated = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dtProjects = new DataTable();
        dtProjects.Columns.Add("ProjectID", typeof(string));
        dtProjects.Columns.Add("ProjectName", typeof(string));

        dtProjects.Rows.Add(0, "--Select--");
        dtProjects.Rows.Add(1, "Project 1");
        dtProjects.Rows.Add(2, "Project 2");
        dtProjects.Rows.Add(3, "Project 3");
        dtProjects.Rows.Add(4, "Project 4");
        dtProjects.Rows.Add(5, "Project 5");


        cmbProject = new EasyCompletionComboBox();

        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

        string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

        ECComboBoxColumn cmb = new ECComboBoxColumn();
        //DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data";
        cmb.Name = "cmb";

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);

    }
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (projectComboBoxPopulated == 0)
        {
            cmbProject = e.Control as EasyCompletionComboBox;
            cmbProject.MatchingMethod = StringMatchingMethod.UseWildcards;
            cmbProject.DisplayMember = "ProjectName";
            cmbProject.ValueMember = "ProjectID";
            cmbProject.DataSource = dtProjects;
            projectComboBoxPopulated = 1;
        }

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The Selected value of the combobox is returning the Display member instead of the value member. For example, if I had selected "Project 3", I should get the ID "3" instead of "Project 3".

Comment: You need to grab the selected object. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050924/c-sharp-datagridview-get-selected-item-in-combobox-columns

Comment: I'm inheriting the DataGridViewTextBoxCell and not the DataGridViewComboBoxCell so those properties are not available. I guess, there lies the problem.